# Regular Expressions help for htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, search-engine

I am interested in **excluding** some documents from being indexed on `search engines`, so I am using `X-Robots-Tag` to achieve it. However, I need to have a regular expression which will select documents within a specific direcotory i.e. `secret document` in my case.

**For Example**

```
    /dir1/dir2/secret documents/file1.pdf
    /dira/dir1/dir2/secret documents/file2.pdf
    /dir1a/secret documents/file3.pdf
    /dir1a/other documents/file4.pdf
```

As you can see, there could be any number of directories on left, but the last directory if is "secret documents", i want to disallow it using following code in  `htaccess`.

**Regular Expression**

RegEx should fit in below

```
<Files ~ "\.pdf$">
  Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
</Files>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
<Files ~ "secret\ documents/.+?\.pdf$">
  Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
</Files>
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava, would you mind explaining what your reg expression does?

Comment: Yes sure. `secret\ documents/.+?\.pdf$` matches literal text `secret documents/` followed by 1 or more length characters (pdf file name) followed by literal `.pdf`.

Comment: `"secret\ documents/\w+\.pdf$"` will also work but it won't match files names such as `"secret documents/some-file.pdf$"` since `\w` doesn't match hyphens.

Comment: another quick question, we have directories before the "secret documents" folder. So would this regular expression still applies to it? This will go in .htaccess to skip documents which are in this sub folder no matter what are the parent folders.

Comment: Yes it will still apply to all the sub folders down from the path where this .htaccess is placed.

Comment: oops, where do i put this .htaccess file? Would it work if I put this snippet in .htaccess placed in root level?

Comment: Yes use the .htaccess at root level.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Files ~ "secret\ documents\/.+?\.pdf$">
  Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
</Files>
```

Don't forget to escape the forward slash after documents.

Comment: Forward slash doesn't need to be escaped in most of the Apache regex.